# Are MojoMotor questions on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

*Note for Moderators: ExpressionEngine has a sister product called [MojoMotor](http://mojomotor.com/), which though much more lightweight, shares it's CodeIgniter DNA (and a very similar templating syntax) with EE, and allows migration to EE if you outgrow it - it could be considered a companion product - hence why I'm asking this question.*

[MojoMotor](http://mojomotor.com) has a small but dedicated community, that I suspect broadly overlaps/is a subset of the EE community. Additionally many of the likely questions that relate to MM are similar in nature to those about EE. I therefore think it's worth asking **should MojoMotor questions be off topic/out of scope for the EE StackExchange?**

NB I think this is a different case to whether or not to [allow pure HTML/CSS qns](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-we-going-to-allow-pure-html-css-questions) as there is much less value for the broader web-dev community in MM qns being answered on (say) SO, much more likelihood of them received a high quality answer here rather than elsewhere, and there are just not likely to be so darn many of them.

Comment: Related: Does anyone actually use MojoMotor?

Answer (score 11):

I would say that MojoMotor questions are off-topic. Just because EllisLab makes it, doesn't mean it's relevant to EE users. Similarly, I don't think pure CodeIgniter questions are relevant here either ("I'm building a CodeIgniter app, how do I load a helper?").

Especially since visitors coming here might then find MM or CI questions with answers that won't fly under EE, causing confusion.

Comment: I agree with Derek. Off topic.

Comment: I agree with Derek, MM & CI questions can be directed to StackOverflow

Comment: Agreed - MM stuff is off topic. I've used EE for years but have never used MM and have no plans to. This isn't "EllisLab SE", it's "ExpressionEngine SE"

Answer (score 4):

Good question.

I have no problem with the questions being here. I'm not sure how many people will be around to answer them, but I think we will find that out soon enough. If MM questions don't end up getting answers then I expect people will just stop asking them here, but if it becomes a big problem we could always ban them further down the line.

I think a `mojomotor` tag would be sufficient to separate MM questions. Like you say, there is a huge overlap in the communities, the products have a similar target market (front end developers), and nearly everyone who uses MM will use EE as well on their larger sites.

If we do approve MM questions, in our FAQ we should make it clear that this site is for ExpressionEngine and MojoMotor questions (though not pure CodeIgniter, they would be waaaay off topic).

Comment: This seems like a sensible approach to me. Going to leave for 24 hrs before accepting as would be good to get some more opinion on this too. Agreed about pure CI being off topic as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also keen to see what other people think about this. At the end of the day, I don't really care either way, but it seems like a shame to abandon MM users.

Answer (score 4):

- How to install the MojoMotor blog add-on should be off topic.
- How to migrate MojoMotor content to ExpressionEngine is however on topic.

I don't think the fact that it's an EllisLab product should have anything to do with it being here and I also don't think the tags being similar has any weight either.

If we are going to include MM we might as well include PyroCMS as well since it's built with CI and the tags are very similar as well.

If the topic includes ExpressionEngine in the title or the context of the question is EE related then it should be fine here other wise I say no, it doesn't belong here. Same goes with CI as others pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say they're off topic. It's an entirely different product and there is likely to be relatively little overlap in questions, even if the user base is similar.

Having built a MojoMotor site earlier this year I'd also be strongly in favour of having the entire software package disappear off the face of the earth never to be seen again. But that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems off topic but (and I'm a EE and MM user) it seems a bit unfair that such a close relate topic (at least from a corporate view) should be treated different. It's almost impossible to bring a big number community to create a StackExchange area for MojoMotor.

With all the changes going on, is this not the time to think as a community, a wider one? Maybe with that approach we could ad a more stronger group. So, with a protocol in the Subject if you don't want to answer you can skip all MojoMotor questions and leave them to us...